# Regex Linux and CSV file

Tags: c, regex, csv

I have a CSV file and I want search some name and surname. The character of separation is ";".
If I have some homonym (when I search for name) then  I search for Surname until I find the person.
How I do with the regex?

Thi is the file:

```
xadamk00;Adamkova;Eva;FIT
xaltri01;Altrichter;Jan;FIT
xantol00;Antolik;Pavel;FIT
xarlet00;Arlet;Filip;FIT
xaronl00;Aron;Lukas;FIT
xbacka00;Backa;Pavel;FIT
xbahur00;Bahurek;Tomas;FIT
xbalha01;Balharova;Lucie;FIT
xbalic00;Balicki;Zdenek;FIT
xbamba01;Bambas;Tomas;FIT
```

Struct of file:

```
login;surname;name;faculty
```

Comment: What is your expected output? You are looking for C solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you tagged your question with `c', but judging from the title, you want it under Linux, so bash/awk should be fine I guess?!

If so: assuming you data file is `test.txt', and you want the entry for Zdenek Balicki, do the following in bash/awk:

```
awk -F ';' '$2 == "Balicki" && $3 == "Zdenek"  { print $0 }' test.txt
```

This will print

```
xbalic00;Balicki;Zdenek;FIT
```

I hope that answers your question. If not, please specify in detail what you mean by `Regex Linux'.